# Testing involving MutableSharedFlow - java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-flow

Apologies for what is probably a very amateur question.
I'm getting to grips with flows and having issues with testing where `MutableSharedFlow` is concerned.

The following is the simplest example I can construct that recreates the problem:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@ExperimentalTime
class MyExampleTest {

    val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    @Test
    fun test() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest  {
        val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()

        sharedFlow.take(2).collect {
            println(it)
        }

        sharedFlow.tryEmit("Hello")
        sharedFlow.tryEmit("World")
    }
}
```

This results int he following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet

    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.getCompletionExceptionOrNull(JobSupport.kt:1187)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:53)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
    at com.example.MyExampleTest.test(MyExampleTest.kt:22)
```

From my limited understanding I think it's something to do with the fact that `SharedFlow` never completes. But I thought having the `take(2)` would mitigate this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my limited understanding I think it's something to do with the fact that SharedFlow never completes.

You're right, this is more or less the problem. Flow is based on Coroutines and the coroutine has not completed.

The best way to unit test Flows in my opinion is Turbine:

https://github.com/cashapp/turbine

```
// Cold Flow
flowOf("one", "two").test {
  assertEquals("one", expectItem())
  assertEquals("two", expectItem())
  expectComplete()
}

// Hot Flow
MutableStateFlow("test").test {
    assertThat(expectItem()).isEqualTo("test")
    cancelAndConsumeRemainingEvents()
}
```

There is also an open issue about this exact "problem":

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204

Comment: This works great with cold flows but still getting similar issues with hot ones :(

Comment: I updated my answer to include a test of a hot flow

Answer (score 0):

Inside tests use `runBlocking` instead of `runBlockingTest`.

For `flow` testing combine it with a launch from scope. E.g:

```
val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)

   runBlocking {
        val job1 = testScope.launch {
            doJobThatNeedsCollect(Unit).collect {
                when (it) {
                    is Success -> {
                        isSuccess = true
                        cancel()
                    }
                    is Failure -> {
                        isSuccess = false
                        cancel()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (!job1.isCancelled) {
        }
        assertTrue(isSuccess)
    }
```